# NullPointerException while sending StringArray using Parcelable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

I have got odd problem while sending intent with parcelable object. This object has got one String array. Using this answer [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents) I have created first my object as parcelable and then send it. This is the fragment of my code:

```
    public class MyObject implements Parcelable{

    private String _title = null;
    private String[] _genre;
    private int _time = 0;
    private String _disc = null;

    private static final String TAG = "MyObject";

    public MyObject (String title, String[] genre, int time, String disc) {
        _title = title;
        _genre = genre;
        _time = time;
        _disc = disc;
    }



    public MyObject(Parcel source) {
            /*
             * Reconstruct from the Parcel
             */
            Log.v(TAG, "ParcelData(Parcel source): time to put back parcel data");
            _title = source.readString();
            try{
                source.readStringArray(_genre);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
            }
        _time = source.readInt();
        _disc = source.readString();
    }

    /*... Getters and setters and other stuff...*/

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        Log.v(TAG, "writeToParcel..."+ flags);
        dest.writeString(_title);
        dest.writeStringArray(_genre);
        dest.writeInt(_time);
        dest.writeString(_disc);
        Log.i(TAG,_genre[0]);
    }

    // this is used to regenerate your object. All Parcelables must have a CREATOR that implements these two methods
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyObject>() {
        public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyObject(in);
        }

        public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObject[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Sending seems ok.

```
Intent displayInfo = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MovieInfo.class);
                    displayInfo.putExtra(OBJECT, mySQLiteAdapter.getEntry(idSet));
                    startActivity(displayInfo);
```

However, when I am trying to get this data

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        myParcel = (MyObject) intent.getParcelableExtra(FBM2Activity.OBJECT);
```

**I am getting NullPointerException from readStringArray**. Does anyone know where I can have got mistake?

Comment: what lines does the null pointer exception happen on? The bottom one?

Comment: No, the null pointer exception happens on line `source.readStringArray(_genre);`. This is why it is surrounded with try/catch. The last line is using constructor where this line is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `_genre = source.createStringArray()`.

The reasoning behind this is that `readStringArray(String[] val)` expects `val` to be a `String[]` that has already been created with the correct number of array elements. The way you are doing it, `_genre` is `null` when you call `source.readStringArray(_genre)`.

Comment: Glad to help. The docs for `readStringArray(String[] val)` don't explain it but I found it out by looking at the source code for `Parcel`. See line 929 in the current source at...https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java The exception would have been caused by the line `if (N == val.length)`